# Close Signalr connection base on time quota

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, background-process, signalr-hub

I need set a timer for signalr connection，to avoid each client use over his time quota, and close the connection . What should I do? Can I use the signalr configuration  or I have to set a background service in the host?
I already set a authentication with json token, so the problem is not at this. the problem is that,I need a timer class which is keep runing and trigger disconnection method on time. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not as simple as close the signalr connection from the server side (which doesn't seem possible anyway), as the client can simply reconnect and get a new connection id. You can build in something in the client or use authentication/identification on top of signalr.

Comment: @huysentruitw   I already set a authentication with json token, so the problem is not at this. I need a timer class which is keep runing and trigger disconnection method on time. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't disconnect a socket connection from the server side, there's no method for that as far as I can see, but you can tell the client to disconnect or put them in groups and remove them from the group after a timeout. This is partially described in the answer of Frank M.

Answer (score 0):

You have to track your users time towards that quota, which is probably best in a database table. You could do this in a cookie or on the client side but that is risky as they could be modified or if they connect from multiple clients (say a phone and a pc).

When a user attempts to connect, you should check that current time against their quota and if they have time remaining.

You can have a method in your client to call to notify them that they are out of time and have the client disconnect.

What you can do on the server side is always push users into groups and when a client is at quota is remove them from the group they are normally in to receive data and push them into a group called something like "outoftime". This group never receives any content. You can do this during the OnConnect() method.

Comment: I already set a authentication with json token, so the problem is not at this. I need a timer class which is keep runing and trigger disconnection method on time. How can I do this?

Comment: As huysentruitw said, you cannot trigger a disconnection within the server side. You can call a method to tell the client to disconnect. You need a way to know how much time an individual has remaining and when it is okay to stay connected or when they should be sent a disconnect.